# Issue setting up Tiller for HA Kubernetes cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have set up a HA Kubernetes cluster containing the following nodes.

1 Nginx Load Balancer
2 Kubernetes Masters
2 Worker Nodes
1 Dev Node (holding kubectl, helm utilities)
I have a dev node where I have kubectl setup and I am able to launch pods.

I have setup the helm client on my dev node.

While setting up tiller using helm init I donot get any error on the devnode, but on the elected master node I get the below errors. The config for kubectl, helm points to the Nginx LB.

```
deployment_controller.go:303] Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.extensions "tiller-deploy": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again 
deployment_controller.go:303] Operation cannot be fulfilled on replicasets "tiller-deploy-687742799": StorageError: invalid object, Code: 4, Key: /registry/replicasets/kube-system/tiller-deploy-687742799, ResourceVersion: 0, AdditionalErrorMsg: Precondition failed: UID in precondition: 0xc422b04010, UID in object meta:
```

Also I am getting infrequent errors some like below
    `pkg/controller/garbagecollector/garbagecollector.go:768: watch of <nil> ended with: very short watch pkg/controller/petset/pet_set.go:148: watch of *apps.StatefulSet ended with: very short watch`

`pkg/controller/resourcequota/resource_quota_controller.go:232: watch of *api.ReplicationController ended with: very short watch`

My Kubernetes cluster details are

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"269f928217957e7126dc87e6adfa82242bfe5b1e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-03T15:31:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"269f928217957e7126dc87e6adfa82242bfe5b1e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-03T15:31:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.5.1", GitCommit:"7cf31e8d9a026287041bae077b09165be247ae66", GitTreeState:"clean"} Error: cannot connect to Tiller
```

Let me know if anything else is required.

Please suggest here.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the canary-image:

```
helm init --canary-image
```

Let me know if there is some suggestion here.

Closing the issue.